# How to wind-proof an existing tent

Tags: tents, wind

I have this tent: [Fjord Nansen Tromvik II](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fjord-Nansen-TROMVIK-II-tent/dp/B01M5IKC46). It's very well built and thought-out, lightweight (around 2kg / 4.5 lbs) and is a pleasure to sleep in during summer / early autumn.  However, since it's so lightweight and very well ventilated (with outer fly not even touching the ground), in windy conditions it feels almost like sleeping without a tent :)

I don't want to buy a second tent at the moment. Is there a simple / inexpensive way to wind-proof this tent? Shall I buy some cloth and sew it to the external tarp to create a skirt?

Comment: I'm surprised those small mesh triangles bother you that much. My tarptent is much more airy as each full side under the vestibule is mesh. Because yours uses fixed poles, I would guess you cannot pitch the fly closer to the ground. I would just adjust your clothing and/or sleeping layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is close up the gap under the fly sheet on the upwind side using something you already have. That's easy for me - I go bike camping and my panniers are heavy duty dry bags that do the job very well (though its only needed on uneven ground with my tent) A rucksack can also be used, especially if you put something in it to give it shape (e.g. boots), but it can end up rather damp from dew.

If you feel the need to use an extra piece of cloth, a bit of tent fabric or plastic sheet could probably close the gap (again on the upwind side) just held in place with your boots; it's worth a try at least.

If you're not already paying attention to the wind direction, you may get enough help by pitching downwind of a bush or wall.